# Grocery CRUD ajax performance

Tags: php, ajax, grocery-crud

I'm using Grocery Crud(1.4.1) with CI 2.1.4. The Grocery Crud worked in my local environment and our internal staging server. However, when we deployed the project to the live server, we ran into the performance issue. The pages which contains Grocery Crud loaded really slowly. Other pages (like login-check with db to login) is good for us. I have checked the "Network" panel in Chrome, looks like the Ajax calls like "ajax_list_info", "ajax_list" took a really long time to be completed (in our case is 30s). Please see the screenshot below:
[image]

I think there might be something with the live server configuration which blocked the Grocery Crud's performance. However, wanted to ask if anyone else has met this issue?

Comment: Maybe there is an index problem? Are you sure that all the database has correct primary keys, indexes... e.t.c. ? Download the database from live and see it this will work for you fast on your local.

Comment: Thanks John. However in our live database, the index is setup correctly. Also, since the project is not released yet, there is only 10 or 20 records in the database.

Comment: That's weird. Can you have some simple Codeigniter queries at your server to see if it is the same slow? This can happen when you have the database in different server. Make sure that you have the database to the same machine and that you have "localhost" at your database configurations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, John. I have checked, the data is coming from the same server. Also, we have a login feature in this application, it's a simple DB query, and this one is fast. Now we have access to see the live server's phpinfo(), could you please give me some advice which module is important (should be turn on or off) for the Grocery Crud? Cheers.

Comment: There is a 404 in your log, for a jquery script, is that normal?

Comment: Nope, that's not he reason. Still thanks, flup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the people who helped me with this issue. As I mentioned in the question, this issue does relate to our live server configuration. The PHP code:

```
session_start();
```

After we removed this line (we are using CodeIgniter's session library, so PHP session_start function is a redundant line in our code....), the application's performance was getting much better.

I'm new in PHP coding, and this one teaches me that if something slows the application performance, always look into the code you wrote first.

Thanks guys.